# should I sue my employer

Tags: salary, california

I resigned from my last position after working for two months and here is the payment related scenario:

Initially employer agreed on X amount per month salary. I worked for 21 days in month M1 and 30 days in month M2 and 5 days in 
month M3 and I resigned after that.

So, for 21 days, he only paid me 41% of the original salary amount X. It's pretty much obivious that since I have worked more 
than half month in the month M1, my salary should be greater than 50%.

**For Month M2 and M3:**

Employer told me that they ran out of funding and they need to conserve cash. For that he reduced my original salary to 1/3rd 
of the original amount X and told me that once the company gets enough cash, he will pay me back the remaining salary amount (2/3rd)
for month M2.

Overall, for month M2 and M3, he paid me 41% of the original amount of X.

Since I have left the company, I have asked him how he is going to handle the deferred payment concept. I have sent him an email
but haven't received any response.

I am wondering should I sue him for the remaining amount if he doesn't agree/respond to my email? I am located in california.

Also, for Month M1, he paid me the salary after 5 days( after the end of month) and for month M2 he paid me the salary after 
10 days and that too after asking him when can I expect the salary.

Also, I asked him whether the salary for month M1 included any tax deduction , he said No. And he told me that he transferred the 
amount for approximate two weeks. Not sure what is approximate here as I have worked for 21 days in the month M1.
I believe it's the same for the M2 and M3 month salary as well. He didn't keep me on the payroll.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions that start with "should I sue..." should be addressed to an attorney.

Comment: @littleadv You want me to change the question title ?

Comment: @John The question of whether to sue or not always depends on the question of whether or not you have a winnable case, and only an attorney looking at all the details can tell you that.

Comment: @BenMiller Thanks. I just wanted to get advise of other people and their thoughts. I can understand it all depends upon the attorney and the case.

Comment: From a personal finances and money standpoint, I'd go to the office in person and request a check for the full outstanding balance. Nothing dramatic, just go and collect.

Comment: @AVProgrammer The problem is that they don't have office yet as its a startup. Everything happened via email/phone.

Comment: @John I'm not a lawyer, and I believe no one of the "resident" respondents on this forum is. I *think* that several laws have been broken, based on my knowledge of the CA labor laws. However, as I said, your question is in essence a request for a legal advice, and only a lawyer can provide that.

Comment: Even though that should not necessarily be a requirement, do you have anything like a written contract, signed by both parties, stipulating the agreed salary and your start date? Anything to prove the days/hours worked, and when you stopped working for them? Were you actually employed, or working freelance for them?

Comment: Yes, written contract is there signed by both parties with start date. I have email date when I resigned.

Comment: In addition to the question of whether you have a winnable lawsuit, you'll also need advice on the cost/benefit of pursuing it, i.e. you might win in court but pay more in fees than you recover from your old employer. I'd try to resolved this directly a few more times, but then you either need a lawyer who can advise or maybe work through a state agency as in the one answer currently posted.

Comment: The blood content of turnips comes to mind.  If they're doing this it's unlikely there will be anything left to collect even if you win.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Why do you think that even if I win, there may not be anything left to collect?

Comment: @John Because it's pretty clear they are in dire financial straights now.  Why would anything be left?

Comment: @LorenPechtel Suppose I win the case and If court orders him or imposes fine on him, don't you think it's his problem to figure out how he is gonna pay? Also, the CEO told me that he is trying to conserve cash and they still have some money left. That's the reason he reduced my salary from Jan onwards was promising to pay the deferred payment once the company gets cash.

Comment: @John If the company runs out of cash what will you be paid with?

Comment: @LorenPechtel If company runs out of cash, isn't it the responsibility of the CEO to figure out how to pay his employees? May be he can sell his things or whatever etc. He should have thought about payment options before hiring new people and agreeing on a particular amount.

Comment: @John No, if it's a corporate structure and it runs out of money, too bad for whoever is owed money.  When my former employer went bust I was missing a couple of paychecks and a few thousand in medical bills that weren't paid--and there was nothing to be done.

Comment: @LorenPechtel I contacted my employer for Jan Feb remaining payment and now he is coming up with an excuse that that I would be getting the remaining balance only I would have worked for the company and company would have got the cash in future. Upon asking where exactly something like this is mentioned in the contract, he is unable to answer.

Comment: For Dec payment, at first he told me no taxes were withheld and I was paid in full without any taxa deductions. Now he is showing me calculations from some online tax calculator  and trying to prove that he paid the right amount. the reality is that I was never on payroll and no paystubs were generated.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your former employer is also in California, the Labor Commissioner / Department of Industrial Relations exists to handle this type of claim. Check out their page on [filing a wage claim.](http://www.dir.ca.gov/dlse/HowToFileWageClaim.htm)

Comment: Thanks. Yes they have registered office location in San Francisco.

Comment: If he claims to have withheld federal income and payroll taxes but didn’t remit them to the IRS, then the IRS will also get involved, both to make sure you get proper credit for the withholding and to get their money.